# Eclipse ADT: Layout Properties Editor doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a new, clean installation of Eclipse Kepler (4.3.1) SR1 (x64) in Linux Mint 15 Olivia x64 (based on Ubuntu 13.04 “Raring Ringtail”). ADT version is 22.3.0, and Java is Oracle's 1.7.0_45.

The problem is, I cannot edit the properties in layout editor; nothing happens when I click "..." button, nor I can edit the properties directly by clicking the empty space. The boolean properties don't even contain the checkbox.

[image: Bugged Properties Editor on Linux]

This doesn't happen in Windows XP 32bit, with the same versions of Eclipse and ADT:
[image: Properties Editor on Windows XP 32bit]

Anyone know any workarounds/reasons for this? Looks like [Mac OS X Mountain Lion had a similar issue in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11579594/android-eclipse-editor-unable-to-edit-properties), but I heard that was fixed, and I'm talking about Linux version here.

I had no such problems in Eclipse Indigo and an old version of ADT, but I can't remember the exact versions of them.

**EDIT**: Lubuntu 13.04 (32bit) in VMware Player doesn't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Selecting the correct target API level in layout editor (click the green droid character)** solved the problem.

I was developing an App using Android 4.1.2 (API 16) SDK but the editor was using various data from Android 4.4 (API 19).

I accidentally thought it was Linux-specific problem because:

- I had Android 4.4 (API 19) and Android 4.1.2 (API 16) SDKs installed in my Linux Mint
- When testing in my Windows XP sub PC and Lubuntu 13.04 Virtual Machine I had only Android 4.1.2 (API 16) SDK installed.